# Reduce height of scrollable frame in CustomTKinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollview, customtkinter

Is there a way to set the height of the `CTkScrollableFrame` in the customtkinter library below 200 pixels?

Short example:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(root, height=100)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The keyword argument `height=100` seems to have no effect. If I choose a value greater than 200 the result gets bigger but I can't find a way to make it smaller.

I also tried `.grid` instead of `.pack` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

It is a design bug of `customtkinter` that the default height of the internal scrollbar inside the `CTkScrollableFrame` widget is 200.

Work around is to set the height of the internal scrollbar explicitly by calling `frame._scrollbar.configure(height=0)` after creating `frame`.

```py
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(root, height=100)
# set the height of the internal scrollbar to zero
# then it will be expanded vertically to the configured height of "frame"
frame._scrollbar.configure(height=0)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good work, detective!

Answer (score -2):

In order change the height of a scroll able frame, you need to use `frame.configure()`

Here's the code:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(root)
frame.pack()

# The height configure thing
frame.configure(height=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Don't forget to give me a upvote if it works :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Did you actually try it to see if it made the window 100 pixels tall? On my system it remained at 200 pixels.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm busy with my projects. 
But this documentation should help you.

Here: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkScrollableFrame

Comment: The point is, this solution doesn't work for a height less than 200.